# Is it possible to 'pull' uncommitted changes from another machine?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Suppose I have two machines with a Mercurial repository with a local copy of some revision, and no uncommitted changes to that local copy. Now I make some local changes on one machine without committing.

Is it possible, on the second machine, to pull/replicate these uncommitted changes as such? i.e. make the second machine apply the same changes, without committing, to its local copy?

**Note:** I'm interested in a single command or one-liner, to be executed on the second machine only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial won't do it for you; you can only push and pull what's in the repository. But if your access to the upstream machine is via unrestricted ssh, you can use it to run a remote `hg diff` and apply the results as a patch. For example (on "second machine"):

```
% hg paths
default = ssh://example.com/path/to/repo
% ssh example.com hg -R path/to/repo diff > uncommitted.patch
% hg import --no-commit uncommitted.patch
```

To elaborate: If you **need** to be able to view the uncommitted files, you can arrange for ssh shell access on the remote machine and do it as above. If the owner of the remote machine doesn't want you to do this, well, mercurial isn't going to help you poke around.

Comment: So the answer is no :-(

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to do something sneaky? (See edit.)

Comment: I work on two separate computers, and I have some changes which really don't merit a commit since I'm halfway into refactoring something. I just want to continue work on the other computer. So, no sneaky stuff. I have ssh access, I just wondered whether mercurial could do it for me. But actually the ssh with the specified command is pretty good.

Comment: Makes sense. You could also wrap the above into a mercurial alias, so that you type, e.g., `hg peek` and it runs the script for you.

Comment: Oh, that's neat. Maybe put it in your answer. Also, note my one-liner suggested below...

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is `hg diff --git > changes.patch` to export all your changes into a file on the first machine and then `hg import --no-commit changes.patch` to import these changes on the second computer.

Comment: `hg export` does not work with uncommitted changes (it'll default to the changes in the parent revision of the working directory). You'll have to use `hg diff` instead.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends Thanks, my fault.

Comment: I want something I can do from the second machine with no extra actions on the first one (otherwise, yes, obviously I can copy a patch.

Comment: without access to the machine with the uncommitted changes you cannot obtain those; going via diff is the only option if you don't want to commit the changes. The current working dir state is *not* part of the repository (yet) and as such not subject to access via network.

Comment: @einpoklum, if you can access the other machine via the network, you can map a drive to the other machine and run this set of commands remotely on the directory to capture the diff and apply it to your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner version of [@Alexis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300902/1593077):

```
ssh example.com hg -R path/to/repo diff | hg import --no-commit -
```

Thanks @ReimerBehrends for suggesting `-` instead of `/proc/self/fd/0`.

Comment: You can use `-` to denote stdin instead of `/proc/self/fd/0`.